# Cannot set variable in if else statement in MySql

Tags: mysql

I created a stored procedure which requirement as below

When I execute the stored procedure with one username typed in which be compare if username are exists in database then (variable) result_userId will set at userId ELSE if username dose not exists in database then (variable) result_userId will be set the number 99

*BUT I CANNOT DO THAT*

Please help me !

::CODE BELOW::

```
DELIMITER $$
USE `shoppy` $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `testProc02`
(
    IN  _username  CHAR(50),
    OUT result_userId   INT UNSIGNED
)
BEGIN
    SELECT @uId := userId FROM user 
    WHERE userName = _username;
    IF @uId = NULL THEN
        SET result_userId = 99;
    ELSE
        SET result_userId = @uId;
    END IF;    
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

When I CALL testProc02();

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e5CaC.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use the equality operator `=` on **`null`**. You have to test the expression `IS NULL` or use the null-safe equality operator `<=>`.

Your code should be

```
DELIMITER $$
USE `shoppy` $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `testProc02`
(
    IN  _username  CHAR(50),
    OUT result_userId   INT UNSIGNED
)
BEGIN
    SELECT @uId := userId FROM user 
    WHERE userName = _username;
    IF @uId IS NULL THEN
        SET result_userId = 99;
    ELSE
        SET result_userId = @uId;
    END IF;    
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

What happens is that `@uID = NULL` always evaluates to **`null`**, which the `if` interprets as **`false`**.

Comment: Thanks a lot, because my WorkBench cannot refesh the result_userId so i verry hard for testing this codes
i dont know why my Workbench is only show the latest result number T_T whether i try to do hard tried